# У меня есть comboBox, в котором я получаю значения TypeName из БД, при выборе значения я должен получить данные из базы и вставить в dataGird

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

```
private void name_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(
           "server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=d_base;");
        string selectQuery = "SELECT TypeName  FROM devices_type";
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        name.Text = "Devices Type";
        name.Items.Clear();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            name.Refresh();
            name.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
            //devicename.Add(name.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
        if (name.Text == "Monitor")
        {
            conn.Open();
            mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(
                "select TypeName from `devices_type`", connection);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            data1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: И? В чём вопрос?

Comment: вопрос в том что мне нужно выброть  значене из бокса, и вставить в датагирд  даннве из базы